# How to get a git's branch with fuzzy finder?

Tags: bash, command-line, fuzzyfinder, fzf

I found [git examples with fzf(fuzzy finder)](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/wiki/examples#git) and they does work great.
like:

```
# fbr - checkout git branch
fbr() {
  local branches branch
  branches=$(git branch -vv) &&
  branch=$(echo "$branches" | fzf +m) &&
  git checkout $(echo "$branch" | awk '{print $1}' | sed "s/.* //")
}

# fbr - checkout git branch (including remote branches)
fbr() {
  local branches branch
  branches=$(git branch --all | grep -v HEAD) &&
  branch=$(echo "$branches" |
           fzf-tmux -d $(( 2 + $(wc -l <<< "$branches") )) +m) &&
  git checkout $(echo "$branch" | sed "s/.* //" | sed "s#remotes/[^/]*/##")
}
```

I have this in my **.bashrc**

```
bind '"\C-b": "fbr \n"'
```

After I press **Ctrl-b** I get to choose a git's branch and it switches right after I press enter, but is there a way to type something first like `git push staging` (and then get the list of branches and put selected branch right where the cursor was before calling the list of branches, and then I press enter to push the selected branch to `staging`)

Ex:
`git push staging` (**Ctrl-b** - choose a branch) and I want to get this output - `git push staging selected_branch`

Comment: Considered git completion? https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

Answer (score 22, accepted):

These are the key bindings I use in bash

- <kbd>CTRL-G</kbd><kbd>CTRL-F</kbd> - Files listed in `git status`
- <kbd>CTRL-G</kbd><kbd>CTRL-B</kbd> - Branches
- <kbd>CTRL-G</kbd><kbd>CTRL-T</kbd> - Tags
- <kbd>CTRL-G</kbd><kbd>CTRL-H</kbd> - Commit hashes
- <kbd>CTRL-G</kbd><kbd>CTRL-R</kbd> - Remotes

Note that `redraw-current-line` is not necessary if you're on tmux.

```
is_in_git_repo() {
  git rev-parse HEAD > /dev/null 2>&1
}

gf() {
  is_in_git_repo &&
    git -c color.status=always status --short |
    fzf --height 40% -m --ansi --nth 2..,.. | awk '{print $2}'
}

gb() {
  is_in_git_repo &&
    git branch -a -vv --color=always | grep -v '/HEAD\s' |
    fzf --height 40% --ansi --multi --tac | sed 's/^..//' | awk '{print $1}' |
    sed 's#^remotes/[^/]*/##'
}

gt() {
  is_in_git_repo &&
    git tag --sort -version:refname |
    fzf --height 40% --multi
}

gh() {
  is_in_git_repo &&
    git log --date=short --format="%C(green)%C(bold)%cd %C(auto)%h%d %s (%an)" --graph |
    fzf --height 40% --ansi --no-sort --reverse --multi | grep -o '[a-f0-9]\{7,\}'
}

gr() {
  is_in_git_repo &&
    git remote -v | awk '{print $1 " " $2}' | uniq |
    fzf --height 40% --tac | awk '{print $1}'
}

bind '"\er": redraw-current-line'
bind '"\C-g\C-f": "$(gf)\e\C-e\er"'
bind '"\C-g\C-b": "$(gb)\e\C-e\er"'
bind '"\C-g\C-t": "$(gt)\e\C-e\er"'
bind '"\C-g\C-h": "$(gh)\e\C-e\er"'
bind '"\C-g\C-r": "$(gr)\e\C-e\er"'
```

Comment: For both bash and zsh, see https://gist.github.com/junegunn/8b572b8d4b5eddd8b85e5f4d40f17236

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Windows, try `git checkout @(git branch -a | fzf).trim()`

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for but for linux. Thank you anyway :)
For Linux you will put it like this `git checkout $(git branch -a | fzf)`